# Settings API - how to update multiple options manually?

Tags: options, settings-api

I'm storing all my options using Settings API:

```
function registerSettings() {

register_setting('XX_theme_settings', 'XX_theme_settings', 'setting_validate' );

add_settings_section('theme_options', 'Theme Options', 'theme_options_generate', 'page1' ); 
add_settings_field( 'XX_Option1', 'Option 1', 'text_input', 'page1', 'theme_options', 'XX_Option1' );
add_settings_field( 'XX_Option2', 'Option 2', 'text_input', 'page1', 'theme_options', 'XX_Option2' ); 

};

add_action('admin_init', 'registerSettings');
```

Let's say I want to update all the options manually (not using forms, but via PHP), how should I do that?

That's how this update looks like for one setting:

```
$my_options= get_option('XX_theme_settings');//retrieve all options
$my_options['XX_Option2'] = 'my new value'; //amend value in array(s)
update_option('XX_theme_settings', $my_options); //update option array
```

I have absolutely no idea how to make it work for multiple (originally I have over 50) setting fields.

I've been trying this way:

```
$current_options = get_option('XX_theme_settings');
$imported_options = array_merge($current_options , array_intersect_key($_POST["import"], $current_options ));
// $imported_options = $_POST["import"]; - simplified
update_option('XX_theme_settings', $imported_options);
```

And it does not work, of course "import" is not a string but an array.

Here's a related (my own) question: [Settings API - how to update options manually?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/settings-api-how-to-update-options-manually)

I guess I still do need to create a PHP foreach loop and loop through all the settings, then list them, ten add every single one via update_option? How to? Would it be slow, because it sounds like it?

**UPDATE**

This code doesn't seem to update the settings:

```
$current_options = get_option( 'XX_theme_settings', array() );
$desired_options = array("existing_field" => "new value");
// $desired_options = array("XX_theme_settings" => array("existing_field" => "new value")); tried this one, but also no luck
$merged_options = wp_parse_args( $current_options, $desired_options );
update_option( 'XX_theme_settings', $merged_options );
```

**UPDATE II**

This is even stranger.

I put the above code at page.php (just for testing reasons):

```
    $current_options = get_option( 'XX_theme_settings', array() );
    $desired_options = array("existing_field" => "new value");
    $merged_options = wp_parse_args( $current_options, $desired_options );
    update_option( 'XX_theme_settings', $merged_options );
```

I refresh one of the pages. Nothing happens. Then I change the code to this:

```
    $current_options = get_option( 'XX_theme_settings', array() );
    $desired_options = array("existing_field" => "new value");
    $merged_options[] = wp_parse_args( $current_options, $desired_options ); //here's the change
    update_option( 'XX_theme_settings', $merged_options );
```

Another refresh, "existing_field" is now emtpy.

Then I once again paste the first code and refresh for the third time and it works.

Hint: maybe I should remove fields value before updating them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fetch current options, and be sure to return an array if empty:

   ```
   $current_options = get_option( 'option_name', array() );
   ```
2. Ensure desired options are in an array:

   ```
   $desired_options = array( /* whatever you need goes here */ );
   ```
3. Merge them, using `[wp_parse_args()`][1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args):

   ```
   $merged_options = wp_parse_args( $current_options, $desired_options );
   ```
4. Update

   ```
   update_option( 'option_name', $merged_options );
   ```

Of course, the trick for you is ensuring that you're dealing with an array with your desired options. Maybe do something like so:

```
$desired_options = array( $_POST['import'] );
```

(P.S. please do some sort of sanitization. `$_POST` data are *inherently untrustworthy*.)

### Edit

> I have around 30 options, inputs, booleans, textareas. They're all
>   stored under XX_theme_settings and one of them is called
>   `existing_field`

Just follow the process laid out above:

1. Fetch current options, and be sure to return an array if empty:

   ```
   $current_options = get_option( 'XX_theme_settings', array() );
   ```
2. Ensure desired options are in an array:

   ```
   $desired_options = array( 'existing_field' => 'your string here' );
   ```
3. Merge them, using `[wp_parse_args()`][1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args):

   ```
   $merged_options = wp_parse_args( $current_options, $desired_options );
   ```
4. Update

   ```
   update_option( 'XX_theme_settings', $merged_options );
   ```

Comment: Hm, @ChipBennett, Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't update any options. I've tried using multidimensional array as `$current_options` and it's the same. I will post an update soon.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your data stored as an option, or the structure of the `$_POST` data, it's impossible to provide a more-specific solution.

Comment: I'm not using $_POST data for now, just this simple array as in example (if it will work then anything will, I hope). I have around 30 options, inputs, booleans, textareas. They're all stored under `XX_theme_settings` and one of them is called `existing_field` (literally :)). I guess it isn't enough data? Maybe I could merge them using PHP functions somehow, not wp_parse_args()? I want this to be universal to be honest, working with many themes / any data. I'm going to bed as it's 3 am here, I will reply tomorrow. Goodnight :)

Comment: The `wp_parse_args()` method will work just fine. See updated answer.

Comment: Does the code from your edit differ from the one from my edit? I'm afraid id still does nothing, I will create new theme from the scratch and try this, maybe there's something wrong with mine. I'm 100% positive I'm using right field name and option name.

Comment: You've not provided enough context. Where and how are you calling the code?

Comment: I'm using the code "as it is", tried on options page and in multiple different files to make sure (such as page.php). The code for updating single field works perfectly everywhere, this one doesn't. Maybe I should wrap this with a function or something?

Comment: check UPDATE II, I think it might help.

Comment: Where and how you execute the code depends on where, why, and how you intend to update the options. Without knowing any of that, it's not possible to provide more precise guidance, other than to say that just dropping the code directly into `functions.php` (not in a callback hooked into an explicit action) or worse, dropping the code directly into the template, is almost certain not to work as you're expecting.